# PyQt5 - cannot create new widgets dynamically on button press to function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The below code is attempting to create new widgets on a button press however when I use a button press to call the function it will not show the widgets in the GUI unless I put "self.createMulipleWidgets()" inside the **init** and have it called immediately. I understand I could do this and then use show()/hide() however this will not work for my program as I need to wait for input from the user before creating the widget plus the user will decide how many widgets are created and their is no way of pre creating all of them as I do not know how many the user will want. Their for I am looking for some way in which no object is created unto a button is pressed.

Any feed back would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import time

"""Application"""
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText("create widgets")
        button.pressed.connect(self.call)

        # self.createMulipleWidgets() cannot use this as it creates widget before user input

    def call(self):
        self.createMulipleWidgets()

    def createMulipleWidgets(self):
        # this will be dune dymanically so cannot be pre made so I cannot use show/hide
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText("create new label")
        label.move(0, 40)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: add `label.show()`

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe I missed that!